# Nvidia Driver Hangs/Freezes

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia

I hava a Compaq Presario CQ60. I recently completely removed windows vista and installed debian. I thought the fresh installation is good, but I found out that on high cpu(probably also GPU) load the screen starts flickering. I searched for the issue and there were answers saying that nouveau is not working with card NVIDIA GeForce 8200M G. I installed nvidia driver for that card, and it was working for around half minute. Then it started to freeze system, and eventually crash.

My system specs:
Graphic Card: Nvidia GeForce 8200M G

Processor: AMD * 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing nvidia legacy 304xx driver.